# Convert looped output into an array

Tags: java

Having a problem converting loop output into an array.  I am converting a decimal into binary form but I want it to print out from left to right rather than in a vertical line.  I assume there is a way to add the loop output into an array 1 by 1.
My code snipet from the program:

```
    if (choice == 2)//convert decimal to binary
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal digit between -512 and 511 to convert to binary.");
        decimal = keyboard.nextInt();
        decimal2 = decimal;
        while(decimal > 0){

            decimal2 = decimal % 2;
            decimal = decimal /2;
            System.out.println(decimal2);


        }

    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you allowed to use `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string to concatenate the remainder values.

```
String ans="";
```

inside the loop

```
decimal2 = decimal % 2;
decimal = decimal /2;
ans = decimal1+ans;
```

outside the loop you print:

```
System.out.println(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `System.out.print(decimal2)` instead of `println()`, which inserts the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible you should use the built-in Java methods, because they are generally more reliable than anything you write:

You can use `Integer.toBinaryString()` to easily convert to from decimal to binary:

example:

```
//read from STDIN
decimal = keyboard.nextInt();

//Converts decimal to a binary representation in String format
String bitString = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);

//print result to STDOUT
System.out.println(bitString);
```

Note: another advantage to doing it this way is all of the digits of the binary number are side by side. Which I believe was your original goal.

Comment: thanks.  The assignment, however, requires that we do it without the built in methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Java conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/CodeConventions.pdf) while writing Java programs...

```
if (choice == 2)//convert decimal to binary {
    System.out.println("Enter a decimal digit between -512 and 511 to convert to binary.");
    decimal = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Binary number is ");
    while(decimal > 0) {
        System.out.print(decimal % 2);
        decimal = decimal / 2;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

If you don't need to write like above, you can use below too

```
System.out.println("Binary of number is : " + Integer.toBinaryString(keyboard.nextInt()));
```

### Good Luck!!!